# How to insert data from one table to another in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, datatable

I have two tables, `visitors` and `in`.

`visitors` contains columns, `Name`, `Number`, `Purpose`, and `Datetime`.
`in` contains `Name`, `Number`, and `InTime`.

I want to fetch all the values from the `visitors` table into `in`. I have tried copying the data from `visitors` to `in`, however, if I add new rows into the `visitors` table, those new rows won't be reflected in my `in` table.

Is there any way I can copy/insert all the data from one table to another in a way that it will also reflect the new added values in the `in` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
$copyNotificationTemplates = MasterNotificationTemplate::query()
                                    ->each(function ($template) use ($organizationId) {
                                    $newTemplate = $template->replicate();
                                    $newTemplate->setTable('notification_templates');
                                    $newTemplate->organization_id = $organizationId;
                                    $newTemplate->save();
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert new rows in visitors, insert that rows in 'in' too so
you don't need to copy or other things.